# Typescript raising an error on a correctly typed parameter

Tags: typescript, next.js, typescript2.0, react-typescript

I am using NextJs and typescript and I when I pass a correctly typed prop the error i get is:

```
./pages/jobs.tsx:100:15
Type error: Type '{ job: jobType; key: number; handleTagClick: (tag: string) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & jobType'.
  Property 'job' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & jobType'.

   98 |           filteredJobs.map((job) => (
   99 |             <JobComponent
> 100 |               job={job}
      |               ^
  101 |               key={job.id}
  102 |               handleTagClick={handleTagClick}
  103 |             />
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The code is here: https://github.com/samrath2007/Internova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JobComponent` is typed as if it receives multiple arguments, but you likely meant for this to be one props object.

Currently:

```js
const JobComponent = (job: jobType, handleTagClick: Function) => {}
```

What it should be:

```js
type Props = { job: jobType, handleTagClick: Function };

const JobComponent = ({job, handleTagClick}: Props) => {}
```